# Conditional update in SQL

Tags: mysql, sql, sqlite

I want a conditional result in my query. I have a column named co1. How can I get

```
15 when c1 > 50
2  when c1 > 20
0 otherwise
```

If I use

```
CASE WHEN (co1>50) THEN 15 ELSE 0 END
```

But when I add the 3rd clause MySQL returns an error

```
CASE WHEN (co1>50) THEN 15 ELSE  WHEN (co1>20) THEN 2 ELSE 0 END
```

What is wrong in the second case? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 6):

`ELSE` should only be in the last clause. Use this:

```
CASE WHEN (co1>50) THEN 15 WHEN (co1>20) THEN 2 ELSE 0 END
```

Answer (score 0):

When you say `ELSE` - you mean it's the last condition. So it should be

```
CASE  
    WHEN (co1>50) THEN 15 
    WHEN (co1>20) THEN 2 
   ELSE 0 
END
```